# MySQL, last in a group (again)

Tags: mysql, group-by

I found tons of examples in Stackoverflow about how to select first and last row in a group but I cannot adapt them to my need. Alas my limited knowledge of MySQL doesn't help.

Some data (date_time, val1 and val2) are saved in random moments. I need to group them for 15 minutes and then calculate, for each 15 min interval:

- number of row in the interval (done)
- val1 min (done)
- val1 avg (done)
- val1 max (done)
- first val2 in the group (done, easy with COALESCE)
- last val2 in the group (**here I need your help**)

Here's my data, desired result, and best effort to date...

```
# what I would like to obtain:
#_timeslice              _count     _min_val1   _avg_val1   _max_val1   _first_val2  _last_val2
# 2017-11-01T00:00:00Z     4          90          100         110          200        210
# 2017-11-01T00:15:00Z     3         100          110         120          240        230
# 2017-11-01T00:30:00Z     2         110          120         130          270        265
# 2017-11-01T00:45:00Z     4          80          112.5       150          290        320

CREATE TABLE `test-table`
    (`date_time` datetime, `val1` float, `val2` float);

INSERT INTO `test-table`
    (`date_time`,         `val1`, `val2`)
VALUES

    ('2017-11-01 00:00:00', 100,   200),  # first 15 min
    ('2017-11-01 00:01:00', 110,   190),
    ('2017-11-01 00:02:05',  90,   220),
    ('2017-11-01 00:14:00', 100,   210),

    ('2017-11-01 00:15:00', 100,   240),  # second 15 min
    ('2017-11-01 00:16:00', 110,   250),
    ('2017-11-01 00:28:00', 120,   230),

    ('2017-11-01 00:30:00', 110,   270),  # third 15 min
    ('2017-11-01 00:44:59', 130,   265),

    ('2017-11-01 00:50:00', 120,   290),  # fourth 15 min 
    ('2017-11-01 00:55:00', 150,   300),
    ('2017-11-01 00:57:00', 100,   280),
    ('2017-11-01 00:58:00',  80,   320)
;

SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date_time`)/900)*900) AS _timeslice,
    COUNT(*) AS _count,
    min(`val1`) as _min_val1,
    avg(`val1`) as _avg_val1,
    max(`val1`) as _max_val1,
    coalesce(`val2`) as _first_val2  # returns the first val2 in the group
    # ----> how to add here the last val2 for the group?
FROM `test-table`
GROUP BY _timeslice;
```

...and here's a fiddle of same [SQLFiddle_grouping_15_min](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9272a/1)

Can somebody help me with the syntax to use?

Comment: Something like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9272a/21

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid with sql_mode = 'only_full_group_by' meaning val2 is random ( https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/ ).. with other words it's pure luck coalesce(`val2`) return's the first value.

Comment: Incidentally, including '-' in table names is a really bad idea.

Comment: Thank you guys for the editing. I had some problems including the code.
About the '-' in table names, I know but it is legacy stuff that cannot be changed together with all other special chars like 'ß', 'ü', etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution with a straightforward syntax. It is possibly the easiest for a newbie like me:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date_time`)/900)*900) AS _timeslice,
    COUNT(*) AS _count,
    min(`val1`) as _min_val1,
    avg(`val1`) as _avg_val1,
    max(`val1`) as _max_val1,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(`val2` AS CHAR) ORDER BY date_time), ',', 1) AS _first_val2,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(`val2` AS CHAR) ORDER BY date_time DESC), ',', 1) AS _last_val2
FROM `test-table`
GROUP BY _timeslice;
```

Fiddle at [SQLFiddle_solved](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9272a/35)

Comment: Oh, maybe it's OK after all.

Comment: I am trying on my data and it works fast and perfectly. Not yet convinced, but I found this SUBSTRING_INDEX+GROUP_CONCAT a number of times around as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM `test-table` a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time)/900) timeslice
            , MIN(date_time) min_date_time 
            , MAX(date_time) max_date_time 
         FROM `test-table` 
        GROUP 
           BY timeslice
     ) b
    ON b.timeslice = FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.date_time)/900)
   AND a.date_time IN(b.min_date_time,b.max_date_time);

+---------------------+------+------+
| date_time           | val1 | val2 |
+---------------------+------+------+
| 2017-11-01 00:00:00 |  100 |  200 |
| 2017-11-01 00:14:00 |  100 |  210 |
| 2017-11-01 00:15:00 |  100 |  240 |
| 2017-11-01 00:28:00 |  120 |  230 |
| 2017-11-01 00:30:00 |  110 |  270 |
| 2017-11-01 00:44:59 |  130 |  265 |
| 2017-11-01 00:50:00 |  120 |  290 |
| 2017-11-01 00:58:00 |   80 |  320 |
+---------------------+------+------+
```